# Win Socket API Delphi 6 отправка сообщений по UDP между клиентом и сервером. Почему порт клиента отличается в серверной и клиентской программе?

Tags: delphi, сокет, delphi-7, udp, winsock

Чтобы более понятна была ситуация выкладываю следующий скринсшот:
[image: Win Socket API Delphi 6 при отправке UDP сообщения порт клиента отличается в серверной и клиентской программах]
Разбираясь в UDP и программированию протокола с использованием Win Socket API в Delphi 6 столкнулся с ситуацией, что почему то в клиентской и серверной программах порт клиента различается.

Я себе ситуацию представлял так, что если клиент привязывает сокет для отправки по UDP в этот момент ему назначается порт, который я в программе вывел в Edit поле. Клиентская и серверная программа у меня запущены на одном ПК, то есть взаимодействие идёт по IP сетевой карты без всяких роутеров. По идее я рассчитывал, что когда я отправлю сообщение серверу, то порт клиента будет совпадать, вот только на практике этого не произошло и порт клиента почему то определился другой, хотя IP определился верный. Тем не менее если с сервера по IP и порту клиента которые определились на сервере отправить клиенту ответ, то клиент его нормально получает.

Не понял что за ситуация. Скажите пожалуйста такая ситуация с портами это вообще нормально? Может это особенность поведения Delphi такая? Если так протоколом и задумано, то может быть кто то знает почему именно так сделали?

Не то что бы мешало продолжать работу над задачей, просто не помешает разобраться почему такая ситуация.

Если потребуются исходники программ на Delphi 6 UDP-клиента и сервера с скринсшота, а так же описание работы программ доступны по ссылке: http://blog.ivru.net/?id=199

Comment: на intel процессорах целые числа хранятся как little-endian, а в сетевых протоколах (UDP, TCP) используется big-endian запись для всех целых чисел, в том числе номеров портов.  переставь местами байты в числе 1953 - получишь число 41223.

Comment: В книге "О чём не пишут в книгах по Delphi. А. Б. Григорьев" которую я частично прочитал было написано про то что процессоры intel и моторола по разному проставляют старший и младший байты порта в записи адреса. При этом указано что функция Delphi htons позволяет не задумываться о указании адреса, например вызовом: SendAddr.sin_port:= htons(7778); кроме того я явно не устанавливаю порт в обоих случаях а его получаю через Edit2.Text:= IntToStr(Addr.sin_port); так что оба порта биндились системой, а затем получались как я показал. Так что считаю дело не в этом. В чем ещё может быть ситуация?

Comment: Egor Skriptunoff, благодарю! Ваш комментарий указал мне на ошибку. Как оказалось в случаи клиента я НЕ использовал ntohs функцию, то есть как Вам выше написал Edit2.Text:= IntToStr(Addr.sin_port); а нужно было Edit2.Text:= IntToStr(ntohs(Addr.sin_port)); а в случаи серверной программы написал с этой функцией вот и получилось что порты разные выводились в Edit поле. На самом же деле порт клиента идентичный определяется что при получении сообщения сервером, что клиентом при бинде сокета.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пользователь - Egor Skriptunoff помог в поиске ошибки. Порт клиента забинденый клиентской программой должен быть такой же как порт клиента на сервере при получении сервером сообщения от клиента.

Ошибка была в том что в клиентской программе я не переставил байты порта из адреса использованием ntohs, а в случаи сервера это сделал. Вот и получилось что порты отличались.